# Keycloak docker upgrade from 4.0.0 Beta to 4.1.0

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to update from Keycloak 4 beta to 4.1.0 docker container:

I've run the migrations:
 `bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=bin/migrate-standalone.cli`,

```
jboss@3322946680a1 keycloak]$ bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=bin/migrate-standalone.cl
*** Begin Migration ***

Adding spi=userFederatedStorage...
{"outcome" => "success"}

Removing declaration for userFederatedStorage SPI
{"outcome" => "success"}

*** End Migration ***
```

These all passed without errors, but when i start my container i get the following error:

```
Node name: 376cb8002a3c, Site name: null
```

Full Log

```
keycloak_1  | 21:35:04,117 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) KC-SERVICES0001: Loading config from standalone.xml or domain.xml
keycloak_1  | 21:35:04,355 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYCLINF0002: Started realmRevisions cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:04,359 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYCLINF0002: Started userRevisions cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:04,371 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYCLINF0002: Started authorizationRevisions cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:04,371 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) Node name: 376cb8002a3c, Site name: null
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,200 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,204 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./auth: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./auth: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
keycloak_1  |   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:84)
keycloak_1  |   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
keycloak_1  |   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
keycloak_1  |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
keycloak_1  |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
keycloak_1  |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
keycloak_1  | Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:162)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2298)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:340)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:253)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:120)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
keycloak_1  |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
keycloak_1  |   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
keycloak_1  |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
keycloak_1  |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
keycloak_1  |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
keycloak_1  |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:565)
keycloak_1  |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:536)
keycloak_1  |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
keycloak_1  |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
keycloak_1  |   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
keycloak_1  |   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
keycloak_1  |   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
keycloak_1  |   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
keycloak_1  |   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
keycloak_1  |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:578)
keycloak_1  |   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
keycloak_1  |   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
keycloak_1  |   ... 6 more
keycloak_1  | Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking method [listUnrunChangeSets] on object [liquibase.Liquibase@1a0bbae4], using arguments [null,(),false]
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.common.util.reflections.Reflections.invokeMethod(Reflections.java:385)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.getLiquibaseUnrunChangeSets(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:284)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.validateChangeSet(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:252)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.validate(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:225)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.migration(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:287)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lambda$lazyInit$0(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:179)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:611)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lazyInit(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:130)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:78)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:186)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:51)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:33)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:186)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.realmLocalStorage(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:143)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getRealmDelegate(RealmCacheSession.java:148)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getMigrationModel(RealmCacheSession.java:141)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.migration.MigrationModelManager.migrate(MigrationModelManager.java:80)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateModel(KeycloakApplication.java:245)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateAndBootstrap(KeycloakApplication.java:186)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:145)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:136)
keycloak_1  |   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
keycloak_1  |   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
keycloak_1  |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
keycloak_1  |   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:150)
keycloak_1  |   ... 28 more
keycloak_1  | Caused by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
keycloak_1  |      1 change sets check sum
keycloak_1  |           META-INF/jpa-changelog-authz-4.0.0.CR1.xml::authz-4.0.0.CR1::psilva@redhat.com was: 7:f72c97037bdb11c6c399e1d14ba2bc65 but is now: 7:57960fc0b0f0dd0563ea6f8b2e4a1707
keycloak_1  |
keycloak_1  |   at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:266)
keycloak_1  |   at liquibase.Liquibase.listUnrunChangeSets(Liquibase.java:1189)
keycloak_1  |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
keycloak_1  |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
keycloak_1  |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
keycloak_1  |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.common.util.reflections.Reflections.invokeMethod(Reflections.java:379)
keycloak_1  |   ... 55 more
keycloak_1  |
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,234 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS]
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,237 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTPS listener https suspending
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,239 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,241 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTPS listener https stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:8443
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,242 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,244 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,246 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,247 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:8080
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,248 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 1.4.18.Final stopping
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,256 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped work cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,257 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped realms cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,258 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = postgresql
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,258 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped client-mappings cache from ejb container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,258 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped loginFailures cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,259 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped clientSessions cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,260 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped sessions cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,260 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped users cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,260 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped offlineClientSessions cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,262 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped keys cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,263 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped authenticationSessions cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,263 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped offlineSessions cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,264 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment keycloak-server.war (runtime-name: keycloak-server.war) in 56ms
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,265 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped actionTokens cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,266 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped authorization cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,268 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped authorizationRevisions cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,270 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped realmRevisions cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped userRevisions cache from keycloak container
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,282 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment "keycloak-server.war" was rolled back with no failure message
keycloak_1  | 21:35:06,291 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0050: Keycloak 4.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) stopped in 83ms
keycloak_1  | identity_keycloak_1 exited with code 1
```

Are there changes to standalone.xml that need to be made in order to upgrade, how can i fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So it seems i was asking the wrong question. It looks like the Dockerfile used in the keycloak containers will start the server using CMD. This enables you to pass any of the boot parameters to the new container.

The param i wanted was `--admin-only` - this allowed me to start the service without prematurely running anything against the old version of the database. Here's how to upgrade Keycloak 4.1.0 while running docker:

1. snapshot database
2. snapshot themes
3. clone entire instance to a safe
   new server

Once safe:

Ensure the new server has the database and keycloak config environment variables correct in you `.env` file:

```
POSTGRES_ROOT_PASSWORD=REDACTED_1
POSTGRES_DB=keycloak
POSTGRES_USER=keycloak
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=REDACTED_2

DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES
DB_ADDR=postgres
DB_DATABASE=keycloak
DB_USER=keycloak
DB_PASSWORD=REDACTED_2
KEYCLOAK_USER=YOUR-NAME
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=REDACTED_2
```

This is my compose file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:

  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:4.1.0.Final
    ports:
      - 8009:8009
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443
    env_file:
      - .env

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.5
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
        - /path/to/your/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

 #this is optional   
  client:
    image: ianneub/network-tools
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "5430:5432"
    command: sleep 60000000

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    secrets:
      - dhparam.pem
      - privkey.pem
      - fullchain.pem
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

secrets:
  dhparam.pem:
    file: ./nginx/dhparam.pem
  privkey.pem:
    file: ./nginx/privkey.pem
  fullchain.pem:
    file: ./nginx/fullchain.pem
```

Start the DB

```
docker-compose up postgres
```

Start the Admin Servvice:

```
docker-compose run keycloak --admin-only
```

You should see:

```
jboss@3322946680a1 keycloak]$ bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=bin/migrate-standalone.cl
*** Begin Migration ***

Adding spi=userFederatedStorage...
{"outcome" => "success"}

Removing declaration for userFederatedStorage SPI
{"outcome" => "success"}

*** End Migration ***
```

If you nginx.conf file is setup correctly, you should be good to go. From here out, docker-compose down && docker-compose up should work fine. This is only a mild variation from the docs at:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/index.html#intro